# Error doing Array Initialization at Class Level

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and started doing Arrays, however I am getting Compilation error with the below code. Pls help

```
public class TestingArrays {

    int[] ank = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] ans = new int[5];

    ans[0] = 2;

}
```

If I comment the line //ans[0] = 2; then the error is gone, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class definition. You are allowed to declare and initialize members and methods. You are not allowed to write code as you would in a function body. Your code would work if you modify like this (Constructor):

```
public class TestingArrays {

    int[] ank = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] ans = new int[5];

    TestingArrays() {
        ans[0] = 2;
    }
}
```

Or even like this (Initialization block) :

```
public class TestingArrays {

    int[] ank = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] ans = new int[5];

    {
        ans[0] = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the initialization in a constructor or instance initializer.

```
TestingArrays() {
  ans[0] = s;
}
```

You cannot have statements within the class body such as setting a value to a field.